# "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\veiw()"

Tags: php, mysql

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError` thrown with message "

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\veiw()"
```

I have tried this code to get data from DB but getting an error.

```
public function index(){

         $user_data=User::all();
         return veiw('backend.User_table')->with('u_data',$user_data);

     }
```

it should view to `User_table` page.

Comment: please include more details in your post, also fix code formatting [(learn more)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/6374527)

Comment: The problem is a typo in the line with `return`. You are calling method `veiw()` instead of `view()`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return veiw('backend.User_table')->with('u_data',$user_data);
```

to

```
return view('backend.User_table')->with('u_data',$user_data);
```